# How can I list commands or scripts in crontab that are running every minute?

Tags: cron

I have a system where crontab is used heavily. Would like to list all of the jobs running every minute so I can consolidate them into one script.

Answer (score 0):

List all jobs in crontab to a text file.

`crontab -l > /tmp/crontab.txt`

List jobs running every minute searching for five asterisks separated by tabs or spaces.

`grep -P "^(?:\*\s*){5}.+$" /tmp/crontab.txt`